Microsoft Open AI Quickstart Failing SummarizeText app
I am trying to use open ai using the quickstarts at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/get-started-with-dotnet-ai-quickstarts/
I'm following the instructions on the 01-HikeBenefitsSummary project in the quickstarts (followed the Summarize Text link).
I got an API key from OpenAI, I added it to the secrets in the 01-HikeBenefitsSummary quickstart. I made sure that I have powershell 7 installed.
I have set the version of the Nuget Microsoft.SemanticKernel to Latest Stable 1.28.0
When I run the sample, it fails on the line:
string response = await kernel.InvokePromptAsync<string>(prompt, new(new OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings() { MaxTokens = 400 }));

The exception thrown is:
Microsoft.SemanticKernel.HttpOperationException: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.'
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: RevocationStatusUnknown
HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
ClientResultException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Can someone tell me how to get around this error? The quickstart seems very straightforward!
